# Start Service from library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, intentservice

I have a project which requires to download some files via intentservice.
The intentservice is present in a library which is consumed in project using JAR.

The app works fine when build with eclipse.
But when app is build using Android Studio I get following error

```
03-30 11:32:17.285     741-2430/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.abc.abc/com.xyzlib.xyzlib.helper.DownloadService (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

When I put explicit entry inside project menifest, I don't get above error. But service still don't run.

```
<service android:name="com.xyzlib.xyzlib.helper.DownloadService" />
```

What can be the issue?
in eclipse I have enable manifest merging.

Comment: problem is in 'com.abc.abc' . it seems thats not your real package .

Comment: it is... I have just changed the name as I can't reveal it online

Comment: my concern is 'com.abc.abc/com.xyzlib.xyzlib.helper.DownloadService'  ,you can see both package name are different .

Comment: yes first one is project package name then "/" then library package name

Answer (score 0):

Presumably Gradle can't find your library. Try following the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/1445599